# Spring boot native query and JPA Repository

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I would like to share all my project Repository interfaces with different database implementation (PostgreSQL, MySQL, ...), but having also some specific Repository with native query, for every db platform.

How can I achieve it? Is it possible to annotate a Repository to be used only with a specific database?

Answer (score 0):

if you can not do it with annotations you could find out the dialect of the database and act accordingly.
an example

```
private boolean isOracle() {
    Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
    Dialect dialect = ((SessionFactoryImpl) session.getSessionFactory()).getJdbcServices().getDialect();
    return dialect.getClass().getName().contains("Oracle");
}
```

so if (isOracle()) you would use your oracleJpaNativeRepository